# simple update query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

After writing a whole lot of much more complicated code that works beautifully, THIS is the code that is giving me issues.

Simple form

```
<form action="res/scripts/editsubscriber.php" method="post">
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
...etc, etc...
</form>
```

Submits to this script:

```
  include('appvars.php');  
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$date =  $_POST['date'];
$time = substr($date, 0, (stripos($date, " ")+1));
$time = str_replace($time, '', $date);
$created = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$time;
$query = "UPDATE newslettersubscribers SET name = '$name', email = '$email', created = '$created' WHERE id = $id)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 }
```

It posts, I've echoed all of the variables, they change just fine, but it still won't update the database. Someone please tell me what i'm missing...

Comment: On a side note: You code is vulnerable for [SQL Injections](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sql_injection)!

Comment: Closing parentheses at the end of your UPDATE statement, but I don't see any opening parentheses?

Comment: parenthesis at the end of line?

Comment: wow... wowowowowowowowowowowowowowow.... you have no idea how long i spent being so frustrated with this... *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- remove extra `)` on your update statement
- read article to avoid `SQL Injection`

  [Best way to **prevent SQL injection** in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

You got a strange trailing `)` in your SQL query. Have you executed it in a SQL client ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ID form input?

```
<input name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Also, you're not escaping sql/html.

Answer (score 0):

This code will compromise your database's security severely. Since none of the parameters are sanitized before being included in the query, anyone with basic security knowledge can take over your application in seconds.

To address the security issues **and** your bug, you may want to look into 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php